Got sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-26,"message":"non-final"} when broadcast to https://blockstream.info/testnet
I am trying to broadcast this transaction and got this error :
Got sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-26,"message":"non-final"} 

What does this error message mean?
FYI this is the transaction I wanted to broadcast, thank you for your support !
020000000001015113867e2fd1243c28fbb148d2032920f96c5803f1c7af468fe332a1d7a1c5210000000000feffffff01e806000000000000160014b9514f31d8d06dd5782988d15f4bc762cf862dad014065f1e4f5ebe884cf006c985de2628fb1afec3ce30d869e66e6a5aabd272dec9a20dc51a79de2115e0f4bb9edf6843f56f12ca07bd63cfa0585943ecb264e1c98b493e566

If you built a psbt, did you sign your psbt with your private key?

I am building a taproot transaction that pays to a p2tr address, and it is a key path spend. It only has 1 input and I already created a valid signature for that

Your transaction has a locktime of 1726321588 which means it can only be broadcasted AFTER Sat Sep 14 2024 13:46:28 GMT+0000
$ hal tx decode 020000000001015113867e2fd1243c28fbb148d2032920f96c5803f1c7af468fe332a1d7a1c5210000000000feffffff01e806000000000000160014b9514f31d8d06dd5782988d15f4bc762cf862dad014065f1e4f5ebe884cf006c985de2628fb1afec3ce30d869e66e6a5aabd272dec9a20dc51a79de2115e0f4bb9edf6843f56f12ca07bd63cfa0585943ecb264e1c98b493e566 
{
  "txid": "01a2c61803936ae58ec4f06e07bc25355db8484b9dde0fd82c9bfcb444878256",
  "wtxid": "c463a7c71c0aaf1dd583155caf47f702fd75f8a4b2922b3eb57c71a93019de2b",
  "size": 150,
  "weight": 396,
  "vsize": 99,
  "version": 2,
  "locktime": 1726321588, // HERE
  "inputs": [
    {
      "prevout": "21c5a1d7a132e38f46afc7f103586cf9202903d248b1fb283c24d12f7e861351:0",
      "txid": "21c5a1d7a132e38f46afc7f103586cf9202903d248b1fb283c24d12f7e861351",
      "vout": 0,
      "script_sig": {
        "hex": "",
        "asm": ""
      },
      "sequence": 4294967294,
      "witness": [
        "65f1e4f5ebe884cf006c985de2628fb1afec3ce30d869e66e6a5aabd272dec9a20dc51a79de2115e0f4bb9edf6843f56f12ca07bd63cfa0585943ecb264e1c98"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "value": 1768,
      "script_pub_key": {
        "hex": "0014b9514f31d8d06dd5782988d15f4bc762cf862dad",
        "asm": "OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 b9514f31d8d06dd5782988d15f4bc762cf862dad",
        "type": "p2wpkh",
        "address": "bc1qh9g57vwc6pka27pf3rg47j78vt8cvtdd4p69xk"
      }
    }
  ],
  "total_output_value": 1768
}


Thank you for your answer!
